# Enforce type in typescript by using interfaces

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using something similar to this https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11235 to render dynamic modals.

The directive has an input that takes the type a the Component that it will render:

```
    @Directive({ selector: '[ngComponentOutlet]' })
export class NgComponentOutlet implements OnChanges {
    @Input() ngComponentOutlet: Type<any>;
    @Input() ngOutletInjector: Injector;
    @Input() ngOutletProviders: Provider[];
    @Input() ngOutletProjectableNodes: any[][];

    @Output()
    ngOutletCreated = new EventEmitter<ComponentRef<any>>(false);

    constructor(
        private _cmpFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes.hasOwnProperty('ngComponentOutlet')) {
            this._viewContainerRef.clear();

            if (this.ngComponentOutlet) {
                let injector = this.ngOutletInjector || this._viewContainerRef.parentInjector;

                if (Array.isArray(this.ngOutletProviders) && this.ngOutletProviders.length > 0) {
                    injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(this.ngOutletProviders, injector);
                }

                const cmpRef = this._viewContainerRef.createComponent(
                    this._cmpFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.ngComponentOutlet),
                    this._viewContainerRef.length, injector, this.ngOutletProjectableNodes);

                this.ngOutletCreated.emit(cmpRef);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to enforce an interface on the components that can be used like this, so that I know that all Components dynamically rendered has a certain function, for example:

```
export interface ModalContent {
    close(): void;
}
```

All the components that are going to be dynamic modals implements this:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class MyCustomModalComponent implements ModalContent {
    close() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then I put it all together

```
@Component({
    template: `<div [ngComponentOutlet]="component"></div>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
    private component: ModalContent;

    showModal() {
        this.component = MyCustomModalComponent; <-- I get the error here
    }
}
```

My problem is that I get the following error in AppComponent:

```
Type 'typeof MyCustomModalComponent' is not assignable to type 'ModalContent'.
Property 'close' is missing in type 'typeof MyCustomModalComponent'.
```

I guess it has to do with how I handle the types along the way, but I'm now sure what the problem is?

**EDIT** I added the entire Directive for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code says `component` is of type `ModalContent` which means it can hold an instance of `ModalContent`.

```
private component: ModalContent;
```

This code assigns an instance of type `Type`, not of type `ModalContent`

```
this.component = MyCustomModalComponent;
```

This code would comply to the type annotations

```
this.component = new MyCustomModalComponent();
```

but you are not supposed to instantiate components yourself but instead let Angulars DI do it for you.

Not sure what you actually try to accomplish though.

**update**

If you actually want to assign a reference to the type, this should work:

```
private component: Type<ModalContent>
```

Comment: I added the entire Directive as a reference. I want to use that in order to be able to dynamically populate a modal with different components. That part of the code works fine. I just don't know how to declare `private component: ModalContent` correctly. If i set `private component: any`, it works just fine

Comment: `private component: Type;` or `private component: Type<ModalContent>;` (not sure about the later)

Comment: You are absolutely correct about `private component: Type<ModalContent>`. Seems very obvious now that I see it :D Thank you! Update your answer and I'll approve it! :)

Comment: Great! Done. . . .